# Converting .mdf database to access database

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a simple Winforms application with a `.mdf` SQL Server database. I want this application to run easily on any machine without having to setup SQL Server, so how can I convert my SQL Server database to an MS-Access database?

If any easier way to make my application easier to run anywhere please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to SQL Server Management Studio
2. Attach your database
3. Right-click on database
4. Task - Export
5. Choose type and continue